# How to use Server Type text instead of Server Type Id when display Server Name Data?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-core-7.0

I work on `blazor with .net core 7` . I face issue I can't displaying Server Type  Instead of Server Type Id when display all servers Name .

so How to change my `GetAll() Function` to get Server Type instead of Server Type Id .

With another meaning I need to display Server Id and Server Name from Server Names class with Server Type from Server Type class.

because not good to display Server Type Id for customer or user use application

so I need to use Server Type from Server Type model with ServerId and ServerNames by Joining ServerTypeId from `ServerNames Class` and `ServerType  Class` .

on service

```
public interface IserverNamesService : IRepository<ServerNames>
    {
    }
```

on controller ServerNames :

```
private readonly IserverNamesService _IserverNamesService;
        public  ServerNamesController(IserverNamesService IserverName)
        {
        _IserverNamesService = IserverName;
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetAll()
        {
            return Ok(_IserverNamesService.GetAll());
          
        }
```

ServerNames Model as below :

```
public class ServerNames
    {
        [Key]
        public int ServerID { get; set; }
        public string ServerName{ get; set; }
        public int ServerTypeId { get; set; }

    }
Server Type Model as below :

   public class ServerTypes
    {
        [Key]
        public int ServerTypeId  { get; set;}
        public string ServerType { get; set;}
    }
```

repository used as below :

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll();
   
}
public class BaseRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    internal AppsRepositoryDBContext _context;
    internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

    public BaseRepository(AppsRepositoryDBContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        this.dbSet = _context.Set<TEntity>();
    }
public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll() => _context.Set<TEntity>().ToList();
}
```

on blazor component ServerNames.razor

```
<table class="class table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Server Id</th>
            <th>Server Name</th>
            <th>Server Type</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var serv in ServerName)
        {
        <tr>
            <td>@serv.serverID</td>
            <td>@serv.serverName</td>
            <td>@serv.serverType</td>
            

        </tr>
        }
    </tbody>

</table>

@code
{
public class ServerNamesClass
    {
        public int serverID { get; set; }
        public string serverName { get; set; }
        public string serverType { get; set; }
    }
    public class ServerTypesClass
    {
        public int serverTypeId { get; set; }
        public string serverType { get; set; }
    }
    private IEnumerable<ServerNamesClass> ServerName = Array.Empty<ServerNamesClass>();
```

Expected Result as below :

```
SeverID  ServerName ServerType
```

**Updated answer**

```
I try answer below but I get error
```

server names doesn't contain definition for ServerType

```
 public IEnumerable<ServerNamesClass> GetAll()
        {
            return _context.ServerNames
                .Join(_context.ServerTypes,
                sn => sn.ServerTypeId,
                st => st.ServerTypeId,
                (sn, st) => new ServerNamesClass
                {
                    serverID = sn.ServerID,
                    server_Name = sn.server_Name,
                    ServerType = st.ServerType
                }).ToList();
        }
```

**Updated answer**

How i working on server type i have my class server names as below:

```
public class ServerNames
    {
        [Key]
        public int ServerID { get; set; }
        public string ServerName{ get; set; }
        public int ServerTypeId { get; set; }

    }
```

**Updated Answer**

By this way I will add New Column Server Type on database Table servernames.

so are there are any way to avoid adding new column now need to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this to return Server Type.

ServerNamesClass

```
public class ServerNamesClass
{
    public int ServerID { get; set; }
    public string ServerName { get; set; }
    public int ServerTypeId { get; set; }
    public string ServerType { get; set; }
}
```

GetAll()

```
public IEnumerable<ServerNamesClass> GetAll() 
{
    return _context.ServerNames
        .Join(_context.ServerTypes,
        sn => sn.ServerTypeId,
        st => st.ServerTypeId,
        (sn, st) => new ServerNamesClass
        {
            ServerID = sn.ServerID,
            ServerName = sn.ServerName,
            ServerTypeId = sn.ServerTypeId,
            ServerType = st.ServerType
        }).ToList();
}
```

And on Blazor component

```
private IEnumerable<ServerNamesClass> ServerName;

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    ServerName = await _IserverNamesService.GetAll();
}

<table class="class table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Server Id</th>
            <th>Server Name</th>
            <th>Server Type</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var serv in ServerName)
        {
        <tr>
            <td>@serv.ServerID</td>
            <td>@serv.ServerName</td>
            <td>@serv.ServerType</td>
        </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: so you mean call Getall on serivce because i use get all on another places and models

Comment: which place is use public IEnumerable<ServerNamesClass> GetAll() 
{
    return _context.ServerNames
        .Join(_context.ServerTypes,
        sn => sn.ServerTypeId,
        st => st.ServerTypeId,
        (sn, st) => new ServerNamesClass
        {
            serverID = sn.ServerID,
            serverName = sn.ServerName,
            serverType = st.ServerType
        }).ToList();
}

Comment: servernames class doesn't contain defintion for servertype class

Comment: see updated post when try apply answer

Comment: but my case is ServerTypeId is int on main class servernames

Comment: i don't need to add servertype so are there are way to avoid when make migrations

Comment: can you check updated answer please

Comment: can you help me please to use server type and ignore server type from adding to database